# Подгрузка данных из Бд в слайдер

Tags: javascript, база-данных, json

Доброго времени суток!
Столкнуля с такой проблемой "Uncaught TypeError: res.forEach is not a function", необходимо из БД подгрузить Name, status,comment
пробовал так, ни как не пойму что за ошибка и как вставлять все три параметра в слайдер

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#testimonial-slider").owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    itemsDesktop: [1000, 1],
    itemsDesktopSmall: [979, 1],
    itemsTablet: [767, 1],
    pagination: false,
    transitionStyle: "fade",
    navigation: true,
    navigationText: ["", ""],
    autoPlay: true
  });
});

$('#button').click(function() {
  var $table = $('#testimonial-slider');
  $table_head = $table.find('#TestName');



var res = {0: "1", 1: "Игорь", 2: "Студент", 3: "Круто", ID: "1", Name: "Игорь", status: "Студент", comment: "Круто"}
      // Перебираем массив
      res.forEach(function(value) {//здесь возникает ошибка Uncaught TypeError: res.forEach is not a function
        for (var key in value) {
          if (Number(key) !== parseFloat(key)) {
            $table_head.append(value[key] )
          };
        };
  });
});
```

```css
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#testimonial-slider").owlCarousel( {
    items: 1, itemsDesktop:[1000, 1], itemsDesktopSmall:[979, 1], itemsTablet:[767, 1], pagination:false, transitionStyle:"fade", navigation:true, navigationText:["", ""], autoPlay:true
  }
  );
}

);
</script><style>body {
  background: #888
}

.testimonial {
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px 20%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.testimonial .pic {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.testimonial .pic img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.testimonial .testimonial-title {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #9e9e9e;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.testimonial .post {
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #bcbcbc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.testimonial .description {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #86868a;
  line-height: 1.8;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.owl-theme .owl-controls {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
}

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-buttons div {
  font-size: 18px;
  background: transparent;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.owl-theme .owl-prev {
  position: relative;
  left: -45px;
}

.owl-theme .owl-next {
  position: relative;
  right: -45px;
}

.owl-prev:before,
.owl-next:before {
  content: "\f177";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: #444;
}

.owl-next:before {
  content: "\f178";
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .testimonial {
    padding: 40px 10%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.transitions.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Подгрузить отзывы</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">

      <div id="testimonial-slider" class="owl-carousel">

        <div class="testimonial">
          <div class="pic">
            <img src="http://bootstraptema.ru/snippets/slider/2016/testimonials/testimonials-1.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <h3 class="testimonial-title">Kihore</h3>
          <small class="post">Web Instruktor</small>
          <p class="description">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
            in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="testimonial">
          <div class="pic">
            <img src="http://bootstraptema.ru/snippets/slider/2016/testimonials/testimonials-2.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <h3 class="testimonial-title">Yana</h3>
          <small class="post">Web Master</small>
          <p class="description">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="testimonial">
          <div class="pic">
            <img src="http://bootstraptema.ru/snippets/slider/2016/testimonials/testimonials-3.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <h3 class="testimonial-title">kristiana</h3>
          <small class="post">Web Programist</small>
          <p class="description">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
            in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
          </p>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- ./owl-carousel -->

    </div>
    <!-- ./col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 -->
  </div>
  <!-- ./row -->
</div>
<!-- ./container -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам не нужен forEach, **вы перебираете не элементы массива, а свойства объекта**. У вашего объекта нет функции forEach.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
debugger;

// Это Ваш пользовательский объект
var obj = {
    0: "1", 
    1: "Игорь", 
    2: "Студент", 
    3: "Круто", 
    ID: "1", 
    Name: "Игорь", 
    status: "Студент", 
    comment: "Круто"
};

// Перебираем свойства объекта
for (var key in obj) {
    if (Number(key) !== parseFloat(key)) {
        $table_head.append(value[key] )
    };
};
</script>
```

Comment: спасибо большое